# Platypus create stand-alone macOS application

Tags: macos, perl, platypus

I am trying to create a macOS application (HighSierra) starting from a perl script using Platypus. The process works smoothly, but the app created uses the Perl interpreter of the computer. I would like to pack the perl interpreter and the required modules in the app created with Platypus so that I can be shipped as a selfcontained app. Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is achievable try Par::Packer ,the PP tool

```
http://search.cpan.org/~autrijus/PAR-0.85_01/script/pp
```

it could be what you are looking for

if you have shipped Perl and you want to use it with non standard modules you can

you can install perl your modules locally using cpan something like the below:

```
cpan> o conf makepl_arg INSTALL_BASE=/mydir/
cpan> o conf commit
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to pack the perl interpreter and the required modules in the app created with Platypus

Why do you think this is necessary?

Perl is a standard component of macOS. It will always be present.

You need to include any nonstandard Perl modules in your application, of course, but the interpreter doesn't need to be included.

Comment: Fine. Let's forget the interpreter. But how do you add modules that have been compiled with cpan on the default interpreter or, more probably, on a dedicated perl installation (perlbrew)? Expecially quite complicated modules such as Tk?